# How to detect in the backend (Spring Boot) if JavaScript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I developed a simple web application using **Spring Boot**. [image]

When I click on the **Delete** button, It's directly deleting the database record. I know It's happening because I disabled **JavaScript** in the browser. Now, the real question is how to detect if **JavaScript** is disabled in the browser in the backend and stop performing any updates when it's disabled. I'm attaching some images for your reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does "stop performing updates" mean?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, deleting a record in the database. Sorry, If my wording was confusing

Comment: You cannot. You can only detect that on the client, what you should do is make the client smarter and instead of a popup goto another page to ask for confirmation when javascript is disabled. Or just do it always so it doesn't matter if you use javascript or not and then you can use JavaScript (with progressive enhancement) to show the page in a popup instead of going to the page. That way it works in both situations.